# How do I display a string to a text box in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is probably a silly question, but I appreciate any help you all can give me.

I'm encountering an error:

> Error 1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a
>   statement C:\Users\NVIDIA\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Amazon
>   Link Converter\Amazon Link Converter\Form1.cs 31  17  Amazon Link
>   Converter

When I'm using the following code:

```
String address;
address = old_link.Text.Remove(0, 22);
new_link.Text = address;
```

I'm pretty sure it's a simple fix as I think I'm getting things mixed up, but I can't figured it out.

Comment: what type of component is old_link and new_link?

Comment: what is old_link and new_link?? I guess those are TextBox, right?

Comment: setting a break point @ new_link.Text = address; what does address contain.

Comment: address contains what it's supposed to contain: the remaining part of the URL I input in old_link

Comment: I put your code in a test application and it works. Are you perchance doing something in the TextChanged Event or any Validation Events ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean by TextChanged Event or Validation Event. Could you clarify? All I'm doing so far is on button click, the program checks old_text length is GT 0 and if it's a valid URL link. If it is, it does the code I posted above.

Comment: Okay so the error magically disappeared. I really have no clue what changed, as it's exactly the same as how it was when I posted this question. All I know is that it's not there any more. So... thanks for your help guys!

Comment: There is no problem with the code that you posted. It works in my test application. The events that I mentioned above are triggered when the content of the TextBox changes. If you step through the code that you have above does it error out on the new_link.Text = address; ?

Comment: I am glad that it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be very lucky if I answer this with the amount of information provided, but can you try the following:

```
String address; 
address = old_link.Text.Text.Remove(0, 22);
new_link.Text.Text = address;
```

**Note the double "Text" (.Text.Text).**

I think that the Text property of your old_link and new_link controls is a textbox, so you need to call the TextBox.Text property, which in your case would be .Text.Text.

Comment: If you read the comments. His problem automagically fixed itself... Who knows actually what was happening :)

Comment: @MarkHall, just thought this may be his case. I've been there and felt very stupid not quite sure when but I remember there was an object with a property named after the type of the property. So you need to call parent.Text.Text or Parent.Control.Control to really access the correct one.